# Scientific P Value with adjusted R Square

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, p-value, descriptive-statistics

I am running Spearman correlation between 2 variables weight and freight both being numeric.

The output I have received from correlation is P value - 0.00E+000 and Rank R Squared is 0.61 and which means they are moderately correlated however I am not able to interpret the p value. Is this because of large number of values I am dealing with? I have 2 million rows of data for both the variables.

Comment: Why are you not able to interpret it?

Answer (score 1):

Your p-value is very small and close to zero. Which means that the correlation is significant. On why and how this it the case. Please see the link here: [Understanding the p-value in Spearman's rank correlation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55288/understanding-the-p-value-in-spearmans-rank-correlation)